# If $f: A \rightarrow B$ is surjective, and $A, B$ are nonempty sets, and $X \subseteq A$, does $f(A) - f(X) = f(A - X)$?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I'm working on a proof, and the proof will be complete if this is true... but I can't find a theorem in my book that explains whether or not this is true.

Comment: Let $B$ contain only one point ...

Answer (score 4):

This is not true.

Let $A = \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$, let $B = \mathbb{N}$ and let $f:A \to B$ via $f((a,b))=a$. This is clearly surjective.

Now, let $X = \mathbb{N} \times \{1\} \subset A$.

Then, $f(A - X) = B$, but $f(A) - f(X) = \emptyset$.

Comment: What I'm trying to prove is that $B - f(X) \subseteq f(A - X)$... I don't quite understand what your comment is saying :(

Comment: @GarrettMassey: Your question asks if $f(A) - f(X) = f(A-X)$. This examples shows an instance where this is false.

Answer (score 2):

If $f$ is injective, but not necessarily surjective, then the claim is true:

Let $y \in f(A - X)$. There is $a \notin X$, such that $y = f(a)$. If $y \in f(X)$, then there is $x \in X$ such that $y = f(x)$. Thus, $f(x) = f(a)$, hence $x = a \in (A - X) \cap X$, which is impossible. Hence, $y \notin f(X)$, i.e. $y \in f(A) - f(X)$. Thus, $f(A - X) \subseteq f(A) - f(X)$.

The second inclusion is always true.